# TypeError: string indices must be integers describe_vpc_endpoints boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, typeerror, boto3, amazon-vpc

when I run my code I get the error

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

This is my code

```
import boto3
import csv

ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')


vpcendpoints = ec2.describe_vpc_endpoints(DryRun=False)['VpcEndpoints']
results = list(map(lambda endpoint:(endpoint['VpcEndpointType'],endpoint['ServiceName'],endpoint['VpcEndpointId'],endpoint['VpcId'],endpoint['DnsEntries'['DnsName']]),vpcendpoints))

for (vpcendpointtype,servicename,vpcendpointid,vpcid,dnsname) in results:
    print (vpcendpointtype+','+ servicename+ ','+ vpcendpointid+ ','+ vpcid+ ','+ dnsname)
```

I think the problem is the ['DnsEntries'['DnsName']] part, but how to resolve that?

Help very appreciated!!!

print out of whole vpcendpoints (cutted & blanked)

```
{'VpcEndpointId': 'XXXXXXXXXXX', 'VpcEndpointType': 'Interface', 'VpcId': 'vpc-XXXXXXXXXXXXX', 'ServiceName': 'com.amazonaws.eu-central-1.logs', 
'State': 'available', 'PolicyDocument': '{\n  "Statement": [\n    {\n      "Action": "*", \n      "Effect": "Allow", \n      "Principal": "*", \n      "Resource": "*"\n    }\n  ]\n}', 'RouteTableIds': [], 
'SubnetIds': ['subnet-XXXXXXXXXX', 'subnet-XXXXXXXX', 'subnet-XXXXXXXXX'], 'Groups': [{'GroupId': 'sg-XXXXXXXXXX', 'GroupName': 'XXXXXXXXXX'}], 'PrivateDnsEnabled': True, 'RequesterManaged': False, 'NetworkInterfaceIds': ['eni-XXXXXXXXXX', 'eni-XXXXXXXXX', 'eni-XXXXXXXXXXXX'], 
'DnsEntries': [{'DnsName': 'vpce-XXXXXXXXXXXXX.logs.eu-central-1.vpce.amazonaws.com', 'HostedZoneId': 'XXXXXXXX'}, {'DnsName': 'vpce-XXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXX-eu-central-1a.logs.eu-central-1.vpce.amazonaws.com', 'HostedZoneId': 'XXXXXXXX'}, {'DnsName': 'vpce-XXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXX-eu-central-1b.logs.eu-central-1.vpce.amazonaws.com', 'HostedZoneId': 'XXXXXXXXX'}, {'DnsName': 'vpce-XXXXXXXXX-XXXXXX-eu-central-1c.logs.eu-central-1.vpce.amazonaws.com', 'HostedZoneId': 'XXXXXXXXXX'}, {'DnsName': 'logs.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com', 'HostedZoneId': 'XXXXXXXXX'}], 
'CreationTimestamp': datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 27, 13, 46, 4, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'Tags': [{'Key': 'Name', 'Value': 'XXXXXXXX'}], 
'OwnerId': 'XXXXXXX'},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have mistake there.:

```
endpoint['DnsEntries'['DnsName']]
```

`DnsEntries` is an **array**:

```
 'DnsEntries': [
                {
                    'DnsName': 'string',
                    'HostedZoneId': 'string'
                },
            ]
```

Thus you have to call it, **for example** assuming an array of length 1:

```
endpoint['DnsEntries'][0]['DnsName']]
```

**Simplified code** which works:

```
for endpoint in vpcendpoints:

    print('VPC', endpoint['VpcEndpointType'],
          endpoint['ServiceName'],
          endpoint['VpcEndpointId'],
          endpoint['VpcId'])        

    for dns_entry in endpoint['DnsEntries']:
        print(" - DnsName: " + dns_entry['DnsName'])
```

Example output:

```
VPC Gateway com.amazonaws.us-east-1.dynamodb vpce-032a826a vpc-aabb1122
VPC Interface com.amazonaws.us-east-1.elasticloadbalancing vpce-0f89a33420c1931d7 vpc-1a2b3c4d
 - DnsName: vpce-0f89a33420c1931d7-bluzidnv.elasticloadbalancing.us-east-1.vpce.amazonaws.com
 - DnsName: vpce-0f89a33420c1931d7-bluzidnv-us-east-1b.elasticloadbalancing.us-east-1.vpce.amazonaws.com
 - DnsName: vpce-0f89a33420c1931d7-bluzidnv-us-east-1a.elasticloadbalancing.us-east-1.vpce.amazonaws.com
```

Comment: thank you for your fast response, now I get the following error  "results = list(map(lambda endpoint:(endpoint['VpcEndpointType'],endpoint['ServiceName'],endpoint['VpcEndpointId'],endpoint['VpcId'],endpoint['DnsEntries'][0]['DnsName']),vpcendpoints))
IndexError: list index out of range"

Comment: @githubnoobieme Maybe you don't have any DnsEntries? Just print them out and check. Your question does not provide such information.

Comment: well I can see the DnsEntries in the AWS console, but I don´t know how to print them out. Thats the problem with the array in the array thing. Sorry I'am a noobie just starting

Comment: @githubnoobieme `print(vpcendpoints)` to print everything. Your code is quite complex, thus it may be difficult to work with at first.

Comment: thank you again, so I can see the DnsName entries, just blanked with X`'DnsEntries': [{'DnsName': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX.secretsmanager.eu-central-1.vpce.amazonaws.com', 'HostedZoneId': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX'}, {'DnsName': 'vpce-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXX-eu-central-1c.secretsmanager.eu-central-1.vpce.amazonaws.com',` what I want to achive is to print this names for all endpoints together with the 4 attributes before. So basicaly it was working already but this DnsName addition kills my code :(

Comment: @githubnoobieme Can you update your question with full print out of `vpcendpoints`. It will be easier to understand what's happening if its well formatted. Comments are not very useful for code snippets.

Comment: @githubnoobieme I added simplified version of the code which works. It could be good starting point for your use case.

Comment: Thank you that helps me a lot ! you are a MVP thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @githubnoobieme No problem. Glad it worked out :-).

Answer (score 1):

Dns Entries is a list. Hence you need to iterate on the DNS entries to pick up the DnsName instead of the considering it as a dictionary.

```
'DnsEntries': [
                {
                    'DnsName': 'string',
                    'HostedZoneId': 'string'
                }
]
```